# Echarts4R: Changing result based on legend selection

Tags: r, shiny, echarts4r

I am using Echarts4r to make a Shiny app. My data frame is wide, and the idea is to show the cumulative sum for the stacked bar chart. I created the variable for cumulative sum called "cum_sum_total" for the 3 programs, but when I un-click some category on the legend, I would like to have a new cumulative sum according with the categories that I choose to keep.

Please, any advice would be really appreciate,

Here the code:

```
data2 <- data.frame(zipcode= as.factor(round(rnorm(10, 87965, 50),0)), program_1 = rnorm(10, 200, 20), program_2 = rnorm(10, 700, 100), program_3 = rnorm(10, 500, 50))
data<- data2 %>% 
  mutate(total = rowSums(across(where(is.numeric)))) %>%
  mutate(per_program_1=round(100*program_1/total,1)) %>%
  mutate(per_program_2=round(100*program_2/total,1)) %>%
  mutate(per_program_3=round(100*program_3/total,1)) %>%
  mutate("per_total"=round(100*total/sum(total),1)) %>%
  arrange(desc(total)) %>%
  mutate(cum_sum_total = round(cumsum(per_total),1)) %>%
  mutate(per_total_label = paste0(per_total |> as.character(), "%")) |>
  mutate(cum_sum_label = paste0(cum_sum_total |> as.character(), "%")) %>%
  mutate(zipcode = fct_reorder(zipcode, desc(total)))

data |> 
  e_charts(zipcode) |> 
  e_bar(program_1, stack = "g", bind=per_program_1, name="A", legend=TRUE, y_index = 0, emphasis = list(focus = "series")) |> 
  e_bar(program_2, stack = "g", bind=per_program_2, name="B", legend=TRUE, y_index = 0, emphasis = list(focus = "series")) |> 
  e_bar(program_3, stack = "g", bind=per_program_3, name="C", legend=TRUE, y_index = 0, emphasis = list(focus = "series")) |>
  e_line(legend=T, cum_sum_total, bind=cum_sum_label, y_index = 1, name = "Cumulative %", emphasis = list(focus = "series"),
         tooltip=list(show=F),
         label = list(
           show = TRUE, formatter = "{b}",
           rotate = 0,
           textStyle = list(fontFamily = "Arial", 
                            fontSize = 10))) |> 
  e_x_axis(name = "Zip Code", show=TRUE,
           nameLocation = "middle", nameGap=50,
           nameTextStyle = list(
             color = "#87786B",
             fontSize = 15), 
           axisLabel = list(fontFamily="Arial",
                            interval = 0, rotate = 30,
                            fontSize=12, color="#87786B")) |>
  e_y_axis(name="n° of visits", index = 0, show = TRUE, 
           nameLocation ="middle",
           nameGap=70, align="right", 
           nameTextStyle = list(
             color = "#87786B",
             fontSize = 12),
           axisLabel = list(fontSize=12, color="#87786B")) |>
  e_legend(itemWidth=30, top = 30, right=10, 
           type="scroll", padding=0,
           selected = list('A' = TRUE, 
                           'B' = TRUE,
                           'C' = TRUE,
                           'Cumulative %' = FALSE),
           textStyle=list(fontFamily="arial", fontSize=12,
                          color="#87786B")) %>% 
  
e_tooltip(#trigger = "item", 
  formatter = htmlwidgets::JS("function(params){return(params.marker + params.seriesName +
                                        '<br>' +
                                        'Total: ' + echarts.format.addCommas(params.value[1]) +  ' (' +
                                        params.name + '%)');}"),
  textStyle=list(fontFamily="Arial", fontSize=12)) |>
  e_animation(duration=1500) |>
  e_toolbox(show =T, top=0, right= 10, itemSize=10, emphasis=list(iconStyle=list(textFill="#6C2C4E"))) |>
  e_toolbox_feature(feature = c("saveAsImage", "restore")) |> 
  e_theme_custom('{"color":["#F8AD3B", "#D15425", "#9CAC3B", "#6C2C4E"]}')
```

Thanks again,
D.

Comment: Where do you want the updated value to go? Right now, you're not using it at all that variable, so I don't know what you want to do with the information/